# Advice needed on how to call multiple methods inside the main method

Tags: java

Right now, I am working on an exercise that requires me to use several different methods to and call all of them in the `main` method. This code specifically asks for a user's filing status and yearly income to calculate the user's deduction amount, tax rate, taxable income, and tax amount in their own seperate methods.
Then in the `main` method, I need to call these methods and print out the value they return based on what the user has inputed. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TaxActivity{
 public static double getDeductionAmount(double filingStatus){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int deductionAmount;
    if (filingStatus==1){
        deductionAmount=6350;
    }else if(filingStatus==2){
        deductionAmount=12700;
    }else{
        deductionAmount=9350;
    }
    return deductionAmount; 
 }
 public static double getTaxBracket(double filingStatus, double yearlyIncome){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double taxRate;
    if (filingStatus==1){
        if (yearlyIncome>=0&&yearlyIncome<9325){
        taxRate=10.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=9325&&yearlyIncome<37950){
        taxRate=15.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=37950&&yearlyIncome<91900){
        taxRate=25.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=91900&&yearlyIncome<191650){
        taxRate=28.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=191650&&yearlyIncome<416700){
        taxRate=33.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=416700&&yearlyIncome<418400){
        taxRate=35.0;
        }else{
        taxRate=39.6;
        }
    }else if(filingStatus==2){
        if (yearlyIncome>=0&&yearlyIncome<18650){
        taxRate=10.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=18650&&yearlyIncome<75900){
        taxRate=15.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=75900&&yearlyIncome<153100){
        taxRate=25.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=153100&&yearlyIncome<233350){
        taxRate=28.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=233350&&yearlyIncome<416700){
        taxRate=33.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=416700&&yearlyIncome<470700){
        taxRate=35.0;
        }else{
        taxRate=39.6;
        }
    }else{
        if (yearlyIncome>=0&&yearlyIncome<13350){
        taxRate=10.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=13350&&yearlyIncome<50800){
        taxRate=15.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=50800&&yearlyIncome<131200){
        taxRate=25.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=131200&&yearlyIncome<212500){
        taxRate=28.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=212500&&yearlyIncome<416700){
        taxRate=33.0;
        }else if(yearlyIncome>=416700&&yearlyIncome<444550){
        taxRate=35.0;
        }else{
        taxRate=39.6;
        }
    }
    return taxRate;
 }
 public static double getTaxableIncome(double deductionAmount, double yearlyIncome){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double taxableIncome= yearlyIncome - deductionAmount;
    return taxableIncome;
 }
 public static double getTaxAmount(double taxableIncome, double taxRate){
        double taxAmount=(double)taxableIncome*taxRate;
        return taxAmount;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your filing status: ");
    System.out.println("1. Single ");
    System.out.println("2. Married Filing Jointly ");
    System.out.println("3. Head of Household ");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter either 1, 2, or 3: ");
    double filingStatus = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Enter your yearly income: ");
    double yearlyIncome = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Your Deduction Amount is: $"+getDeductionAmount(filingStatus));
    System.out.println("Your Tax Rate is: "+getTaxBracket(filingStatus,yearlyIncome)+"%");
    System.out.println("Your Taxable Amount is: $"+getTaxableIncome(deductionAmount,yearlyIncome));
    System.out.println("Your Amount of Tax Due is: $"+getTaxAmount(taxableIncome,taxRate));
 }
}
```

However, when I run the code, I get these errors:

```
TaxActivity.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println("Your Taxable Amount is: $"+getTaxableIncome(deductionAmount,yearlyIncome));

symbol:   variable deductionAmount
location: class TaxActivity



TaxActivity.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println("Your Amount of Tax Due is: $"+getTaxAmount(taxableIncome,taxRate));

symbol:   variable taxableIncome
location: class TaxActivity



TaxActivity.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("Your Amount of Tax Due is: $"+getTaxAmount(taxableIncome,taxRate));

symbol:   variable taxRate
location: class TaxActivity
3 errors
```

I'm still beginning in Java, so calling methods is still a new concept to me, but I can't seem to see what could be causing these errors. I made sure to make all the variables the same type, and used the right parameters for all of the methods. The only thing I can think of that might be causing problems is an error in the code's formatting that I am unable to notice. I'd appreciate it if any of you could point out what could be causing this error.

Comment: Have you seen this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Comment: `getTaxableIncome(deductionAmount,yearlyIncome));` is a compile error because you never define the variable `deductionAmount` inside the scope `main`.

Comment: Your code is uncompilable. You will need to declare the variables `deductionAmount` and `taxableIncome` and assign values to them

Answer (score 1):

You can't access variables in one method that were created in another method.

Your main method has the line:

`System.out.println("Your Taxable Amount is: $"+getTaxableIncome(deductionAmount,yearlyIncome));`

But there is no variable `deductionAmount` in your main method. You did run the function to compute it, but you never saved it to a variable in your main method. You should have done:

`int deductionAmount = getDeductionAmount(filingStatus);`

Similarly with `taxableIncome`.

Answer (score 0):

You should store return value of your `getDeductionAmount(filingStatus)` method In your main method.
like float `deductionAmount = getDeductionAmount(filingStatus)` then you have to pass your deduction amount to `getTaxableIncome(deductionAmount,yearlyIncome)` method.

Similarly you should store taxable income and taxRate also. 
Then do what ever you want with that variables like printing and passing to other methods.